# Shortcut chain of completablefuture based on a condition

Tags: java-8, completable-future

I want to skip chain of completablefutures based a specific condition. I tried the solution proposed at [chaining several completionstage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406290/chaining-several-completionstage-only-if-a-condition-is-achieved#), but it doesn't seem to work. Here it the code:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class ExceptionHandlingTests {
@Test
public void test1() {
    CompletableFuture<Integer> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Completing result1. Result: " + result.isDone());
        result.complete(10);
    }).thenCompose(x -> {
        System.out.println("Completing result2. Result: " + result.isDone());
        result.complete(10);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(5);
    }).thenCompose(x -> {
        System.out.println("Completing result3. Result: " + result.isDone());
        result.complete(10);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(5);
    }).applyToEither(result, Function.identity());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Completing result1. Result: false
Completing result2. Result: true
Completing result3. Result: true
```

Even though the "result" completablefuture is marked completed, subsequent completablefutures are still executed. How to skip Completablefuture 2 and 3?

Comment: Why did you expect them to be skipped? These stages are entirely unrelated to `result`.

Comment: I thought that's what applyToEither does based on earlier stack overflow anwer. I provided the link in the description. Is there a way to skip rest of the completable futures in this case?

Comment: In the linked answer, there are two futures and only one of them will be completed. Since the other is never completed, its dependent stages are not evaluated. The property of `applyToEither` just is not to wait for the other. But `applyToEither` alone is not sufficient to prevent the evaluation of stages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have created a dependency chain like this:

```
  first
    ↓  (↘)
   next  result
    ↓  ↙
  final
```

The `(↘)` is an explicit completion call `result.complete(…)`, but all other completions happen automatically. The `final` stage, created via `applyToEither` will be completed with either of the prerequisites, whichever is completed first, but does not modify the behavior of them.

In principle, any code could invoke `complete` on it without affecting either of these stages that *might* complete the `final` stage otherwise. The same applies to cancellation. Calling `cancel` on a stage will complete the stage, your calling the method on, without affecting the stages you used to construct it.

The answer of the linked question creates stages like

```
    first
   (↙)  (↘)
 next 1  result
   ↓     |
 next 2  |
   ↘    ↙
    final
```

The key point is, the initial stage will complete either of two `CompletableFuture`s explicitly, not triggering an automatic completion. The other chain of dependent stages will never get evaluated. Since the `final` stage is an `applyToEither`, the completion of only one of the chains is sufficient to evaluate the final function. It still does not affect the prerequisite stages.

Note that for your chain, consisting of `thenCompose` operations, you can implement a similar logic in a simpler fashion, due to the fact that your functions return a `CompletableFuture` anyway. So simply returning a new `CompletableFuture` that will never be completed when you want to shortcut, solves the issue. You can even rewrite your initial `runAsync` to use `thenCompose` instead:

```
for(int shortCutAt: IntStream.range(0, 4).toArray()) {
    System.out.println("Example execution with "
                      +(shortCutAt==0? "no shortcut": "shortcut at "+shortCutAt));

    CompletableFuture<Integer> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null).thenCompose(justVoid -> { // runAsync
        System.out.println("Completing result1. Result: " + result.isDone());
        if(shortCutAt == 1) { result.complete(10); return new CompletableFuture<>(); }
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(justVoid);
    }).thenCompose(x -> {
        System.out.println("Completing result2. Result: " + result.isDone());
        if(shortCutAt == 2) { result.complete(10); return new CompletableFuture<>(); }
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(5);
    }).thenCompose(x -> {
        System.out.println("Completing result3. Result: " + result.isDone());
        if(shortCutAt == 3) { result.complete(10); return new CompletableFuture<>(); }
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(5);
    })
    .applyToEither(result, Function.identity())
    .thenAccept(fr -> System.out.println("final result: "+fr));

    System.out.println();
}
```

```
Example execution with no shortcut
Completing result1. Result: false
Completing result2. Result: false
Completing result3. Result: false
final result: 5

Example execution with shortcut at 1
Completing result1. Result: false
final result: 10

Example execution with shortcut at 2
Completing result1. Result: false
Completing result2. Result: false
final result: 10

Example execution with shortcut at 3
Completing result1. Result: false
Completing result2. Result: false
Completing result3. Result: false
final result: 10
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Holger.

Comment: Thanks @Holger. I refactored the solution to improve reusability. Wrapped up the approach in a simple class called `ShortCircuitCF` with methods to propagate the result or complete the completablefuture. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/mohansunkara/9d32bb08ec6e9eb18f88ff4527dccf9f)